# JSON.parse(...).forEach is an error on published website

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i'm currently working with rendering some graphs on a web mvc project. The graphs already render on my machine when i'm debugging the code, but the moment I publish it on the IIS of my QA server, I get the following error on console

> TypeError: JSON.parse(...).forEach is not a function

Here's the a snippet of the code I'm currently working

```
    ajaxPostConstancy.done(function (html) {
                        Utils.Alerts.HideGif();
                        var data = {};

                        var category = [];
                        var colors = [];
                        JSON.parse(html).forEach(function (e) {
                            category .push(e.date);
                            colors.push(e.color);
                            data[e.date] = e.data1;
                        })
....
```

any ideas of what's going on?

Edit: the *html* var inside the JSON.parse is te string returned by this code

```
public async Task<string> GetCompositionGraph(string contract, string methodName)
        {
            string preFormat = null;
            try
            {
                string method = _configuration["Position:method:" + methodName];
                PositionBL _bl = new PositionBL(Request, Response, _baseUri, method);
                object model = await _bl.PostCompositionGraph(contract);
                preFormat = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.error = ex.Message;
            }
            return preFormat;
        }
```

edit 2: the content of html variable which is generated by the code on the first edit:

> html content:
>   [{"color":"#162ECB","date":"20","data1":1122954.8708},{"color":"#E03473","date":"00","data1":1323061.6168},{"color":"#CE029D","date":"26","data1":29982.2271}]

and this picture is the result I get from the JSON.parse when I debug my website
[image: and this picture is the result I get from the JSON.parse when I debug my website]

Edit 3: Visual input

The explorer console when the sites is deployed on my localhost for debugging
[image: The explorer console when the sites is deployed on my localhost for debugging]

The explorer console while checking the site published on QA server
[image: The explorer console while checking the site published on QA server]

Edit 4: So i narrowed it down to the fact that the error comes when I debug the websit in *Release* mode, so that's kind of a step foward

Comment: What is `html`?

Comment: At a guess, if it parses successfully but `forEach` isn't a function, you're parsing an *object* not an array. But `html` is a weird name for some JSON.

Comment: @VLAZ i added an small explanaiton for the html var

Comment: Sorry, I misread. But what is the content of `html`? You're showing how it's generated but we cannot even say what real data this produces. It might be `null` for all we know or a plain object. In fact, the code hints at that but I don't know. Can you show what is the JSON this fails for?

Comment: @VLAZ I added the content and a visual of the graph that renders on  my localhost but not when published

Answer (score 0):

If `preformat` returns `null` or an **object** `forEach()` will throw an error.

```
ajaxPostConstancy.done(function (html) {
    Utils.Alerts.HideGif();
    var data = {};

    var category = [];
    var colors = [];
    var parsedDatas = JSON.parse(html)

   if (Array.isArray(parsedDatas)) {
       parsedDatas.forEach(function (e) {
           // logic here
       });
   } else {
       console.warn('This is not an array : ', html)
   }
...
```

Comment: the problem here is that the forEach() is working perfectly on my localhost but when published suddendly I get TypeError: JSON.parse(...).forEach is not a function, and both times it consults the exact same API on the exact same server. And I know is not a communication problem because all the other APIs work perfectly on both sites

Answer (score -2):

The forEach() method calls a function once for each element in an array while the JSON.parse() makes the `html` an object.